# field_info_instance returns empty in hook_uninstall

Tags: entities, installation

In a custom module, I'm creating a new field and instance for a custom entity type like this:

```
function mymodule_install() {
  if (!field_info_field('mymodule_field')) {
    $field = array( .... );
    field_create_field($field);
  }
  if (!field_info_instance('mymodule_entity','mymodule_field', 'bundle1')) {
    $instance = array( .... );
    field_create_instance($instance);
  }
}

function mymodule_uninstall() {
  if ($instance = field_info_instance('mymodule_entity','mymodule_field', 'bundle1')) {
    field_delete_instance($instance);
  }
  if (field_info_field('mymodule_field')) {
    field_delete_field('mymodule_field');
  }
  field_purge_batch(100);
}
```

...and the field and instance gets created properly. However upon uninstalling the module, only the field tables are being deleted while the field instance is still there in the `field_config_instance` table **still having** *deleted = 0*.

Debugging the uninstall process reveals that `field_info_instance` (and `field_read_instances`) is returning NULL...

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? I'm on a fresh Drupal 7.23 install...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `field_delete_instance` separately, because `field_delete_field` has it inside.

According to `deleted` column in field_config (you can skip this value in field_config_instance if you're deleting whole field) debug `field_delete_field` function.

Comment: `field_delete_field()` still doesn't delete the entry in the `field_config_instance` table...

Comment: `field_config_instance` entry will be removed only after all `field_data_` and `field_revision_` entries are deleted. May be your batch size in purge is not big enough. Check the `deleted` column in field_config, field_config_instance and names of deleted field tables to be sure that field_delete_field was completed successful.

Comment: The field tables are deleted successfully and also their entry in `field_config` is completely removed. The purging function is doing well.. However `field_config_instance`still contains the instance entries with `deleted = 0`..

Comment: Try to run drush cron manually now, it should get cleared otherwise you have a trouble somewhere :)

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. Well, I guess my OP still remains unsolved. Quite odd since it's on a fresh 7.23 install.

Comment: Were fields added correctly? May be some exotic contrib modules? :) Because I have almost the same code in one of my module and it works fine on 7.23.